# Convert Nested Array into Nested Hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

Without knowing the dimension of array, how do I convert an array to a nested hash?

For example:

```
[["Message", "hello"]]
```

to:

```
{{:message => "Hello"}}
```

Or:

```
[["Memory", [["Internal Memory", "32 GB"], ["Card Type", "MicroSD"]]]]
```

to:

```
{{:memory => {:internal_memroy => "32 GB", :card_type => "MicroSD"}}}
```

or:

```
[["Memory", [["Internal Memory", "32 GB"], ["Card Type", "MicroSD"]]], ["Size", [["Width", "12cm"], ["height", "20cm"]]]]
```

to:

```
{ {:memory => {:internal_memroy => "32 GB", :card_type => "MicroSD"}, {:size => {:width => "12cm", :height => "20cm" } } }
```

Comment: Your first example is not a nested array, but a hash inside an array.

Comment: In more detail - why does 

    [["Memory", [["Internal Memory", "32 GB"], ["Card Type", "MicroSD"]]]]

have the outer level of array? Technically that could be interpreted as a key (i.e. the whole array at the next level of nesting is the key) but no value in the outermost hash - you may need to provide more examples or explain how the arrays are being constructed so that all your cases can be covered

Comment: @Mischa Sorry, for the typo..

Answer (score 1):

Considering your format of nested arrays of pairs, that following function transforms it into the hash you'd like

```rb
def nested_arrays_of_pairs_to_hash(array)
  result = {}
  array.each do |elem|
    second = if elem.last.is_a?(Array)
      nested_arrays_to_hash(elem.last)
    else
      elem.last
    end
    result.merge!({elem.first.to_sym => second})
  end
  result
end
```

A shorter version

```rb
def nested_arrays_to_hash(array)
  return array unless array.is_a? Array
  array.inject({}) do |result, (key, value)|
    result.merge!(key.to_sym => nested_arrays_to_hash(value))
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
> [:Message => "hello"]
=> [{:Message=>"hello"}]
```

Thus:

```
> [:Message => "hello"][0]
=> {:Message=>"hello"}
```

Comment: sorry just noticed you were responding to the original code which was then modified.